# On-premise service health monitoring

Tags: .net, service, soa, health-monitoring

What is the best way of monitoring health of services/daemons used internally (in the local network)? Obviously, all these cloud services periodically pinging target sites is not an option.

Ideally, would need something to be installed on premise, what could listen to periodic http messages coming from the target services themselves. In case of signals not received for a prolonged period of time, notifications should be sent (e.g. via email).

So far all services are written in .NET and for security reasons only outbound connections to the public network are allowed.

Comment: Take a look at Consul.io

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are looking for is a runtime profiler. The answer is ETW tracing.

You should use PerfMonitor.

Take a look on these links:

http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751538(v=vs.110).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2010/08/02/perfmonitor-runanalyze-a-quick-performance-checkup-for-your-managed-app.aspx

Comment: Well, not exactly. The goal here is more a health tracking (whether service is alive or not), not performance tracking. Moreover, services would be installed on different remote machines, while PerfMonitor can only observe processes on the local machine.